# Save a certain number of decimal places to a file

Tags: save

I would like to save data to a txt file. I use for this

```
PutAppend[ " x= ", N[x], " y= ", N[y], "D:/Users/.../file.txt"]]
```

But the number of decimal places that Mathematica writes to the file does not suit me, I would like to have more decimal places, for example 30.
So I rewrote this code as follows:

```
PutAppend[ " x= ", N[x,30], " y= ", N[y,30], "D:/Users/.../file.txt"]]
```

But the number of decimal places recorded in this file remains unchanged and ranges from 14 to 17. Could you explain to me how I can save the number of decimal places I need in a file?

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that x is a machine number with 15 or 16 valid digits. Therefore, you can not get more than 16 digits out of it.

E.g.: consider:

```
x=1/3. //Full Form
```

[image]

This is a machine number. If you try to get 30 digits, you do not get more digits:

N[x,30] //FullForm

[image]

However, if you have a number with more digits, like:

```
x=1/3
```

This ha an infinite number of valid digits.Therefore if you say:

```
N[x, 30]
```

[image]

you get 30 digits in this case.